# Joining two record sets into one result including NULL values

Tags: join, sql-server-2012, group-by, null

I have sql script like below:

```
select a.Program,a.COUNTS_OPEN,b.COUNTS_CLOSE
from 
(select Program, count(ISNULL(Program,'UNKNOWN')) COUNTS_OPEN
from table_a
WHERE (SUBMITDATE > CONVERT(datetime, '2014-08-31 23:59:59.000') and SUBMITDATE < CONVERT(datetime, '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000') ) 
group by Program) as a 

full JOIN

(
select Program,count(ISNULL(Program,'UNKNOWN')) COUNTS_CLOSE 
from table_a
WHERE  (STATUS='Closed' and UPDATEDATE > CONVERT(datetime, '2014-08-31 23:59:59.000') and UPDATEDATE < CONVERT(datetime, '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000') ) 
group by Program) as b
on a.Program= b.Program
```

and in the result there are two rows of NULL, But I'm expecting for one row NULL as it's grouped by program. here is the result set:

```
Program COUNTS_OPEN COUNTS_CLOSE
NULL        NULL              8
NULL        18            NULL
ProgramA    253           205
ProgramB    2              2
ProgramC    123            109
```

in stead of two rows NULL, I need one row like:

```
  Program   COUNTS_OPEN COUNTS_CLOSE
    NULL        18            8
    ProgramA    253           205
    ProgramB    2              2
    ProgramC    123            109
```

can't figure it out how to how to join correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your table structure this is a guess, but I think this query using conditional aggregation should accomplish what you want:

```
SELECT 
    Program, -- replace with ISNULL(Program,'UNKNOWN'), if you want UNKNOWN instead of NULL
    COUNTS_OPEN   = SUM(case when (SUBMITDATE > CONVERT(datetime, '2014-08-31 23:59:59.000') and SUBMITDATE < CONVERT(datetime, '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000') ) then 1 else 0 end), 
    COUNTS_CLOSED = SUM(case when (STATUS='Closed' and UPDATEDATE > CONVERT(datetime, '2014-08-31 23:59:59.000') and UPDATEDATE < CONVERT(datetime, '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000') ) then 1 else 0 end) 
FROM table_a
GROUP BY program
```

Comment: when I group by convert(nvarchar(10),SUBMITDATE,112) and use convert(nvarchar(10),SUBMITDATE,112) as Dates instead of program, COUNTS_CLOSED is not counting correctly. because I know for specific date like 20140901 there is no closed record but result is 2 closed items. do you have any idea?

Comment: @Tayir Sorry, I don't quite understand your question. In any case, if you have a follow-up question it's probably better to post it as a new question so more people than me can see it and help you.

Comment: thanks for reminding me. I created a new question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417559/sql-conditional-aggregate-function-with-date-type